# Outlook 2016 alert/reminder if I do not receive an e-mail from a certain e-mail address for 24 hours

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I receive e-mail(s) everyday (Not always the exact same time) from a certain e-mail address.

I need a way of being alerted if I do NOT receive any e-mails from this address in a specified time, 24 hours is fine.

I do not want a search folder or anything like that relies on me checking constantly. I need an alert or some sort of notification that is obvious.

I've looked at the rules and nothing appears to be able to do this.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think outlook can do this. You can play with NOT rules in the sense that you can have rules fire and abort rule processing, but you can't really define the 24 hour time, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: Sounds like you need to be asking how to change the logic of the email you are receiving. Instead of receiving an email everyday for condition=x, receive an email for condition NOT=x.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is not feasible to realize this using the built-in feature in Outlook. You may submit this idea in the [Outlook UserVoice forum](https://outlook.uservoice.com/) so that the related product team might see and consider adding it in the future verions of Outlook.